# Pandas: groupby to sum subsets of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns. I would like to calculate the sum of various subsets of this columns and assign a name to each group of columns.

Is it possible to achieve this using groupby or other pandas methods?

**Setup:**

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 5)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

columns_groups = {'First': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                  'Second': ['D', 'E'],
                  'Some': ['A', 'C', 'D'],
                  'All': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']}
```

**Desired output:** (is there a more elegant solution?)

```
out = {}
for name, group in columns_groups.items():
    out[name] = df[group].sum(axis=1)

out = pd.DataFrame(out)

out
Out[22]: 
   All  First  Second  Some
0   27     22       5    19
1   23      8      15    13
2   17     11       6     9
```

**My attempt:**

```
df.groupby(columns_groups, axis=1).sum(axis=1)

Out[21]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: P.s. suggestions for a better title are welcome

Comment: Any reason you're specifically after a `groupby` method?

Comment: I "feel" like this case might be covered by groupby, so I'd like to know more about its syntax or other pandas methods

Comment: I really like the idea of using a `dictionary` like this to `groupby` but unfortunately it is not possible afaik. If we `df.transpose()` we could technically use `df.groupby(dictionary)` to group by index and name our groups, but then `key` has to be the value in `index` and `value` the name of our group. This obv wont work in this case since the index will occur multiple times in different groups. Would be a cool feature though (to be able to do it on your kind of `dict`) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a different and fun way , using `reindex` with `MultiIndex`

```
df=df.reindex(columns=sum(columns_groups.values(),[]))
t=[(x,z ) for x , y in columns_groups.items() for z in y]
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(t)
df.sum(level=0,axis=1)
   First  Second  Some  All
0     22       8    18   30
1     17       9    16   26
2      6      15    14   21
```

Comment: Not planning to use it in my code, but it does indeed give a 'group-by' like solution

Answer (score 1):

Is this okay with you:

```
pd.DataFrame({k: df[v].sum(axis=1) for k, v in columns_groups.items()})

   All  First  Second  Some
0   27     22       5    19
1   23      8      15    13
2   17     11       6     9
```

It's same what you did, only in comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually do it in a one-line pandas operation. More memory efficient and super easy

```
file['sum']=file.sum(axis=1, skipna = True)
```

The output below

```
    All  First  Second  sum
0   27   22     5       54.0
1   23   8      15      46.0
2   17   11     6       34.0
```